# How to show XML document in View returned by Controller (MVC)

Tags: model-view-controller, controller

I am building a MVC application in which i am consuming a webservice in my contorller which conntects to a webservice MyWebService. MyWebService has a webmethod GetProjects which takes two parameters. Return type of GetProjects is XmlDocument

Following is the cpde

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyWebService service = new MyWebService();
        XmlNode xmlNode = service.GetProjects("12345", "54321");
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter xmTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
        xmlNode.
       return Content(xmlNode, "text/xml")
        };
```

Above program is running good.

I want to show the XmlDocument returned by controller in view.

In short how to show a XML document in view returned by Contoller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `ViewData [xmldata] = xmlNode.OuterXml;` and in your view you can use `ViewData[xmlData]`.

Full code is as folows:

`public ActionResult Index()

    {

        MyWebService service = new MyWebService();

        XmlNode xmlNode = service.GetProjects("12345", "54321");

        ViewData [xmldata] = xmlNode.OuterXml

       return view();

     }`